# Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005) problem on insertion of value

Tags: c++, windows, memory

I am trying to create an AVL Tree and insert a node into it. Whenever I try to add a data value ın the tree node, my program crashes and returns the value 0xC0000005. This is how I have introduced the data item in the header file:

```
class AVLTreeNode
{
    public:
        int data;
        AVLTreeNode();
        virtual ~AVLTreeNode();
        AVLTreeNode(int d, AVLTreeNode *leftChild, AVLTreeNode *rightChild);
        AVLTreeNode *leftc;
        AVLTreeNode *rightc;
        int height;
}
```

Whenever I try to run the following lines of the code in the insert function, I get the crash.

```
AVLTreeNode *nw = NULL ;
nw->data = v;
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please help me.

Comment: `AVLTreeNode *nw = NULL ;
nw->data = v;` This is Undefined Behavior. Create an object instead.

Comment: The pointer has to point at an instance (also known as object) in order to use the methods and variables in it. You are now saying the `AVLTreeNode *nw` is "NULL". Then, you are accessing the NULL pointer to set values. Make sure the pointer is pointing at an object

Comment: @PeterRuderman Why do you keep adding windows? There is no reason to have a windows tag here.

Comment: The return code 0xC0000005 is Windows-specific.  It happens when your program crashes with an access violation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because explaining that you cannot dereference a null pointer isn't going to be useful to future readers. They already know, because C++ is for people that are serious about programming.

Comment: The OP is clearly a beginner, but that does imply he is unserious.  He took the time to narrow the crash down to a specific line and posted a [mcve] as this site requires.  Understanding the meaning of the 0xC0000005 return code is also useful, general knowledge.

Comment: @pet: The code is neither minimal nor complete. As a beginner who *is* serious about programming, you have at least 1 text book lying next to you. And really, pointers are covered in *any* introductory material. Besides, there are so many questions about access violation exceptions around here, that we really do not need a new one. What's more, not a single of the proposed answers explains, what's *really* going on. This is "undefined behavior", and any compiler can do what it sees fit. Run this through Clang and you'll get radically different results.

Comment: This is how Clang would [interpret the code](https://godbolt.org/z/3Dq37M).

Answer (score 1):

The return code of 0xC0000005 means `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`.  (You can find this and other NT status codes on MSDN: [NTSTATUS Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx).)  The error happens because `NULL` is outside the range of valid addresses for your program.  Before dereferencing a pointer variable, you must assign it the address of a valid object.  For example:

```
AVLTreeNode* nw = new AVLTreeNode{};
nw->data = v;
```

Comment: Sidenote: `AVLTreeNode nw;` should also work. General rule of thumb is to avoid dynamic allocation until it's forced upon you.

Comment: An AVL tree is one of the cases where dynamic allocation is the most practical solution.

Comment: Node. Shoot. For some reason I though t this was the tree. Node yes, dynamic. Tree, probably automatic.

Answer (score -1):

```
AVLTreeNode *nw = NULL;
```

This line of code sets `nw` to be a null pointer, in other words, it doesn’t point at anything. Trying to dereference a null pointer will result in undefined behaviour. You need to allocate memory for an `AVLTreeNode` object, and then get `nw` to point at it.

What you need instead is this, which allocates memory and points `nw` at it:

```
AVLTreeNode *nw = new AVLTreeNode;
```

And remember, whenever you allocate memory with `new` you need to deallocate it when you're finished with it:

```
delete nw;
```

Comment: *"in other words, it points at gibberish"* - No that's not what it means. `NULL` (or `nullptr`) is the designated value to mean, that a pointer doesn't point anywhere. *"Trying to access a null pointer will always get you a runtime error."* - Again incorrect. Accessing a null pointer is always safe. *Dereferencing* a null pointer, on the other hand, leads to undefined behavior. This may or may not result in a runtime error.

Comment: I think I found the answer for my question thank you for your answers

Comment: @IInspectable you’re quite right, I’ve updated my post to reflect your corrections.

Comment: *"Trying to dereference a null pointer will always get you a runtime error."* - Incorrect. What happens when you dereference a null pointer is explicitly undefined in the language specification. **Anything** can happen. A compiler might reject the program, if it discovers undefined behavior. Or it could apply optimizations, that don't result in a runtime error. Play around with [different compilers](https://godbolt.org/) and see how vastly they differ when they compile a program that exhibits undefined behavior.